# Fill key not working?

Tags: modeling

When I try to fill some faces in they either turn black or don't fill at all (other times it works, being finicky), any idea why this could be?

Comment: You selecting vertices, edges or faces when you say it doesn't work? Because the functionality is a bit different. Often I have the F key make the face, but it's pointing in the other direction so you don't see it.

Comment: ^I was wondering if that was why. Would I need to flip the normals if that were the case? I select edges usually.

Comment: When they don't fill in, could it be that the :Backface culling" box. has somehow got itself ticked? (N-->Shading)

Comment: Yes when you are in edge select mode and you fill a face there's no visual cue for the face actually being created if the normal is pointing away from camera and you have backface culling on (as you should always have IMO). If you tab into face select mode you should see a dot in the middle if face was created. Of course if the normal is pointing the wrong way you can do CTRL-N in edge select mode too to flip it.

Comment: It is because you might be in edit mode, change back to object mode and try it